# CapsLock-i, j, k, l as Cursor Keys?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, cursor

I want to map the cursor keys to CapsLock-i, j, k, l

On WinXP/32, is this possible *system-wide* (for all applications)?

(don't need standard CapsLock functionality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [TouchCursor](http://touchcursor.sourceforge.net/).

It can be easily configured to activate when the Caps Lock key is held down and works well across all programs.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script:

```
CapsLock & i::Send {Up}
CapsLock & j::Send {Left}
CapsLock & k::Send {Down}
CapsLock & l::Send {Right}
```

Comment: Does this preserve auto-repeat? When I press CapsLock-i in a Texteditor and hold it, then the cursor should move to the right until I release CapsLock-i.

Comment: @feklee: Yes. (just tested in a text editor on Windows Vista)

Comment: Cool - thanks! It's good to know that there is an alternative to TouchCursor, in case that doesn't meet my expectations.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map cursor keys or anything related with mapping keys. You should take a look at [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Some samples for you :

- http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic54525.html
- http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic33373.html